# Call load() after ajax Success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a partial page re-load after my ajax POST returns successful. I have tried putting the load() function in the Success callback but it never gets triggered. I know it's not a problem with the load() function itself because I can run it in the console and it works fine. How do I run it on success? Thanks.

```
    $("#saveNewTask").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
                alert("Error creating new task");
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#mainTaskWrapper').load('/Tasks #mainTaskWrapper');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `'/Tasks #mainTaskWrapper'` does not seems to be a correct url?

Comment: @ArturFilipiak you are correct. it's a url `/Tasks` and a selector `#mainTaskWrapper`. it is correct.

Comment: Most likely, either `$('#mainTaskWrapper')` doesn't exist or your ajax request is failing.

Comment: @KevinB Looks like the issue is that I'm making the ajax post from an iframe (kendo window) and had to use `$('#mainTaskWrapper', window.parent.document);` to select the div. However this wasn't working either. I eneded up just making an event on the parent page to reload the partial page and triggering that event from the iframe success function. Not great but works for now.

Comment: Here is what I had fwiw:

`var mainWrapper = $('#mainTaskWrapper', window.parent.document),
       mainWrapperId = mainWrapper.attr('id');
$(mainWrapper).load('/Tasks #' + mainWrapperId)
`

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out.. I was calling the ajax post from an iframe and the `#mainTaskWrapper` did not exist on that page but the parent doc. I had to get the element by using `$('#mainTaskWrapper', window.parent.document)`.

Here is my final code to refresh the div on the parent doc.
`var mainWrapper = $('#mainTaskWrapper', window.parent.document), mainWrapperId = mainWrapper.attr('id'); $(mainWrapper).load('/Tasks #' + mainWrapperId)`